# creating a hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

im a c++ student and im just trying to learn how to create a hash table. i have the hash coding part down but i don't know how to implement the table in to the coding part. if someone could give me help it would be great. thanks

```
Movies::Movies(string fn){loadMovies(fn);}

int Movies::getMovieCount() const {return movieCnt;}

 int hashcode(string title)
{
    int hash = 0; 
int factor = 0 ; 
for (int i = 0; i<title.length(); i++)
    hash = factor* title.at(i);
return hash;
}

const Movie * Movies::getMovie(string mc, int& mn) const {
if(mc.length()==0)
    return NULL; // not found
else {
    string mcP = myToLower(mc);
    int ndx=0;
    for(;ndx<movieCnt &&
        (myToLower(movies[ndx].getTitle()).find(mcP)==
        string::npos);ndx++);
    mn = ndx<movieCnt?ndx+1:0;
    return ndx<movieCnt?&movies[ndx]:NULL;
}
 }

Movies::~Movies() {
delete[] movies;
movies = NULL;
} 

void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
ifstream iS(fn);
string s;
getline(iS, s); // skip heading
getline(iS, s);
movieCnt=0;
movies = new Movie[MAX_MOVIES];
while(!iS.eof()) {
    movies[movieCnt++] = Movie(s);
    getline(iS, s);
}
iS.close();
reSize();
}

void Movies::reSize() {
Movie * m = movies;
movies = new Movie[movieCnt];
for(int i=0;i<movieCnt;i++)
    movies[i] = m[i];
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to reduce the code to something small and specific to the use case of performing look-up in a hash-table.

Comment: I think there is an error in your hashcode() function... it should be "hash += factor* title.at(i)", not "hash = factor* title.at(i)".  Otherwise the value returned by hashcode() will depend only on the final character in the string.  Also, if "factor" is always zero, then hashcode() will always return zero no matter what.

Comment: Also, `reSize()` leaks memory, because you're not calling `delete[] m` at the end.